# Swap divs (rows) only in tablet view

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two basic divs that I display side by side in my Bootstrap layout. In using mobile first, I have a search panel div display first, followed by another div.  In desktop mode, using push/pull I correctly get the first div to go to the right.

In the middle view, tablet view, the divs are stacked, but I want to swap their order.  I've created a Bootply:  http://www.bootply.com/I8IUuYNTWK#

In summary:

```
Mobile:
   [search]
   [slideshow]

Tablet:
   [slideshow]
   [search]

Desktop:
   [slideshow] [search]


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="search_div" class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
            search form here (this should be on the right on desktop, on top for mobile, and second for tablet)
        </div>
        <div id="slideshow_div" class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
            slide show here  (this should be on the left for desktop, second for mobile and on top for tablet)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've seen dozens of ways to attempt this but so far all seem odd, not very clean.  I'd also rather not duplicate the divs and hide show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder them in tablet screen size using flex reordering. Check the compatibility table for [**Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

1. Include `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px)` to target
   the tablet screen size width.
2. Use a custom class with row to avoid affecting all the rows.
3. Make sure the `flex-direction` is set to `column` for the stacking effect.

```css
#search_div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}
#slideshow_div {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .reorder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #search_div {
    order: 2;
  }
  #slideshow_div {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row reorder">
    <div id="search_div" class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
      search form here (this should be on the right on desktop, on top for mobile, and second for tablet)
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow_div" class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
      slide show here (this should be on the left for desktop, second for mobile and on top for tablet)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, but it's affecting all my .rows.  Tried assigning an ID to the parent row div but then it stopped working.

Comment: Well, correct that.  Tried it again, assigning flex via the ID of the div and now it works.

Comment: Updated the compatibility table link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox lets you set the order of elements. It's easily done using a media query and a few flexbox rules. You can go without the bootstrap grid on this one and just use flexbox. I forked your bootply if you want to see it in action (http://www.bootply.com/O3HNHn1ULt)

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
   .row { 
        display: flex; 
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .row > #search_div { 
        order: 2;
    }
    .row > #slideshow_div {
        order: 1; 
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .row > #search_div { 
        order: 2;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .row > #slideshow_div { 
        order: 1; 
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: What is the support for flexbox?  Are all the modern browsers supporting it?